# Precedence of ! * ++ requiring parentheses?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Is the C expression:

```
!(*(++buffer))
```

The same thing as:

```
!*++buffer
```

?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: The only other way to place balanced parenthesis causes tokens to be broken up, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Rhymoid tokenization is done before association is considered

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, since the OP is asking about C, not C++ (though they are very similar) suggest using this link: <http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html>

Answer (score 5):

Yes they are essentially same. Here precedence doesn't come into picture because the expression is unambiguous.

Deference `*` is dependent on the result of `++` and argument of `!` is result of expression `*++buffer`. So any other order is simply not possible. (If you don't believe, try to put parenthesis `(...)` in a way that the result of expression is different)

For readability you may put some parenthesis, but it is matter of style than any requirement.

Comment: suggest: always write code for ease of readability and understanding.  In general, this means using parens even when not absolutely necessary.   Note: not everyone has the complete 'C operator precedence' table memorized.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have to ask, use parenthesis.**

There's no sense worrying and confusing later programmers.  If you're not sure, just use parenthesis  -- They're *FREE*.

Comment: Agreed: readability is usually more important than minimality.

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis are not required here.

According to the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the unary `++` prefix operator, the unary indirecton operator `*`, and the unary logical NOT operator `!` all have the same precedence level, and they associate right to left.

Also, since `buffer` is the only base expression contained in the larger expression, there is no other way for the operators to match up.

Comment: As a very special case, the parenthesis might be needed though, for `+++i` and similar obfuscated, artificial expressions. IIrc the compiler would treat such as `++(+i)` ("max munch") which would yield a compiler error because there's no lvalue to increment, while `+(++i)` compiles.